# How to define SQL database tables and form relationship?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this flat file (csv) that I am trying to convert into a SQL database. I can't figure out how to set up 3 tables and form a relationship between them.

Flat file (csv):

```
Ticker   Date       Price    RSI  
xyz    11-12-2019    50      30
xyz    11-13-2019    55      32
xyz    11-14-2019    50      29
abc    11-12-2019    10      29
abc    11-13-2019    15      32
abc    11-14-2019    20      33
```

3 desired database tables:

Table `Stock`:

```
Ticker (primary key)
xyz
abc
```

Table `Price`: (what can be the primary key since all columns can be repeated?)

```
Ticker     Date    Price
xyz    11-12-2019    50      
xyz    11-13-2019    55      
xyz    11-14-2019    50      
abc    11-12-2019    10      
abc    11-13-2019    15      
abc    11-14-2019    20
```

Table `RSI`: [any way to remove Ticker, Date, Price since they are already stored in table `Price`? What will be the primary/ composite key?]

```
Ticker   Date       Price    RSI  
xyz    11-12-2019    50      30
xyz    11-13-2019    55      32
xyz    11-14-2019    50      29
abc    11-12-2019    10      29
abc    11-13-2019    15      32
abc    11-14-2019    20      33
```

Comment: Is the issue creating the tables or populating them?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add an auto incremented integer column ID as primary key

Table Price:

| ID | Ticker | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xyz | 11-12-2019 | 50 |
| 2 | xyz | 11-13-2019 | 55 |
| 3 | xyz | 11-14-2019 | 50 |
| 4 | abc | 11-12-2019 | 10 |
| 5 | abc | 11-13-2019 | 15 |
| 6 | abc | 11-14-2019 | 20 |

Table RSI: use id column of price table as foreign key instead of ticker, date and price. Price_id is the foreign referencing ID column of price table.

| price_id | RSI |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 29 |
| 4 | 29 |
| 5 | 32 |
| 6 | 33 |

Or if RSI has one to one relationship with price then just remove price table and RSI table will serve your purpose.